# Is there a way for me to set the value of a row based on the value of another in an update?

Tags: sql-server

I have code where only one of these three updates will run depending on the value TestStatusId

```
    UPDATE  UserTest
    SET     StartedDate = @Date,
            TestStatusId = 2
    WHERE   UserTestId = @UserTestId
    AND     UserId = @UserId
    AND     TestStatusId = 1

    UPDATE  UserTest
    SET     StartedDate = @Date,
            TestStatusId = 2
    WHERE   UserTestId = @UserTestId
    AND     UserId = @UserId
    AND     TestStatusId = 3

    UPDATE  UserTest
    SET     StartedDate = @Date,
            TestStatusId = 10
    WHERE   UserTestId = @UserTestId
    AND     UserId = @UserId
    AND     TestStatusId = 4
```

Does anyone have any suggestion if there is a way that I could combine these updates into just the one update?

Comment: you will need condition and select

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, there is:

```
UPDATE  UserTest
SET     StartedDate = @Date,
        TestStatusId = CASE WHEN TestStatusId IN (1,3) THEN 2 ELSE 10 END
WHERE   UserTestId = @UserTestId
AND     UserId = @UserId
AND     TestStatusId IN (1,3,4);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I didn't know about IN so that's a big help